# a4j:commandLink working intermittently

Tags: status, ajax4jsf, intermittent, commandlink

In the code below,  a4j:commandLink (with id id="account-link") does not work for me all the time.

Fail Scenario (happens 1 out of approx 10 clicks) : Its clicked, the a4j:status tag (we show a moving wait bar) is invoked but the backing bean is not called. Below is the entire code. The backing bean is conversation scope.

```
            <rich:dataTable id="accountsDataTable" value="#{accounts}" var="acct"
                         styleClass="data-table" rowClasses="odd,even"
                         sortMode="single"
                         rows="50" rendered="#{accounts != null and accounts.rowCount>0}">
                <rich:column id="col1" sortable="true" sortBy="#{acct.customerAccountId}">
                    <f:facet name="header">Account Number</f:facet>
                    <a4j:region id="account-link-zone">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="#{identity.isBackOffice}">
                                <a4j:commandLink action="#{accountSearch.getAndBypassAccount(acct.customerAccountId)}"
                                                 value="#{acct.customerAccountId}" eventsQueue="accountSearchQueue"
                                                 styleClass="left"/>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <a4j:commandLink action="#{accountVerificationAction.getAccountToVerify(acct.customerAccountId)}"
                                                 id="account-link"
                                                 reRender="verificationModal"
                                                 ajaxSingle="true"
                                                 value="#{acct.customerAccountId}" eventsQueue="accountSearchQueue"
                                                 styleClass="left" limitToList="true"/>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </a4j:region>
                     <a4j:status startStyle="left" id="account-link-status" for="account-link-zone">
                         <f:facet name="start">
                             <img alt="status" src="../../img/spinner-inline.gif"/>
                         </f:facet>
                         <f:facet name="stop">
                         </f:facet>
                        </a4j:status>
                </rich:column>
```